# Too many arguments

Tags: sql, visual-studio, iif-function

I have the below piece of coding :-

```
=IIf(IsNothing(((Sum(Fields!TotalCost.Value, "Accrued") + Sum(Fields!TotalCost.Value, "serv1")) / (Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value, "serv1") + Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value, "Accrued"))), (45), 
((Sum(Fields!TotalCost.Value, "Accrued") + Sum(Fields!TotalCost.Value, "serv1")) / (Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value, "serv1") + Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value, "Accrued")))
```

which when run in Visual Studio 2008 returns the below error:-

> BC30057] Too many arguments to 'Public Function IsNothing(Expression
>   As Object) As Boolean'.

Can anyone advise on what the error may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IsNothng takes only one argument. You have 3.

[IsNothing Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5adx7fxz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

But i think you should move one parenthesis:

from

```
=IIf(IsNothing(
```

to

```
=IIf((IsNothing
```